# What do I need to get Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.dll?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using visual studio 2012 and tfs 2013. The problem i am facing is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.dll is missing. But i have other dlls such as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkitemTracking.Client.
Can anyone tell why the dll is missing? Is there any way to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0?

Comment: yes. i checked.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.dll is not there also.

Comment: Have you tried a reinstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution.

I have added a nuget package called 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client'.
After installing this package i got 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.dll' in the folder.